CORS Issue with AWS Lambda and API Gateway HTTP API
I am trying to handle a POST request to an AWS Lambda function via API Gateway HTTP API, but I keep encountering a CORS error. Here is the setup:
API Gateway Configuration:
Type: HTTP API (not REST API)

CORS Settings:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

Lambda Function Code:
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ses = new AWS.SES({ region: 'us-east-1' });

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600', // Cache for 1 hour
  };

  if (event.httpMethod === 'OPTIONS') {
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: headers,
      body: '',
    };
  }

  if (event.httpMethod === 'POST') {
    const { name, email, message } = JSON.parse(event.body);

    const params = {
      Destination: {
        ToAddresses: ['email'], // Replace with your verified email address
      },
      Message: {
        Body: {
          Text: {
            Charset: 'UTF-8',
            Data: `Name: ${name}\nEmail: ${email}\nMessage: ${message}`,
          },
        },
        Subject: {
          Charset: 'UTF-8',
          Data: 'New Contact Form Submission',
        },
      },
      Source: 'xxx@gmail.com', // Replace with your verified email address
    };

    try {
      await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Message sent successfully!' }),
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return {
        statusCode: 500,
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Failed to send message.' }),
      };
    }
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 405,
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Method Not Allowed' }),
  };
};

Problem:
Despite the above configuration, I receive the following CORS error when trying to submit the form:

Access to fetch at 'https://cl4dhs3yg7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/contact' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Steps Taken:

Ensured the Lambda function includes CORS headers for both OPTIONS and POST responses.
Verified that CORS settings in the API Gateway are correctly set.
Deployed the API after making changes.
Tested with CURL commands for preflight and actual requests, but the preflight request returns no output.

Preflight Request:
curl -i -X OPTIONS https://cl4dhs3yg7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/contact \
-H "Origin: http://example.com" \
-H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" \
-H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type"

Actual POST Request:
curl -i -X POST https://cl4dhs3yg7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/contact \
-H "Origin: http://example.com" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"name":"hari", "email":"hari987@gmail.com", "message":"test message"}'

Additional Details:
I am using the HTTP API, not the REST API in API Gateway.
No specific parameter mappings have been added.
Question:
What could be causing the CORS preflight request to fail, and how can I resolve this issue to ensure the correct CORS headers are returned?

Ensured the Lambda function includes CORS headers for both OPTIONS and POST responses.
Verified that CORS settings in the API Gateway are correctly set.
Deployed the API after making changes.
Tested with CURL commands for preflight and actual requests, but the preflight request returns no output.


Origin is not a CORS-safelisted request header, and you don't include it in your allowed headers.  (Content-Type is, so you including it has no effect)

"but the preflight request returns no output." - it would only return headers, no body, since you send an empty body!

Run curl with -v to see the response headers

@Tibrogargan - your remarks regarding Origin header make no sense at all - Origin IS sent in browser requests, and does NOT need to be an "allowed header"

@JaromandaX yes, it's sent in browser requests.  But it's not listed in the Access-Control-Request-Headers shown by the OP

and doesn't need to be @Tibrogargan

I have added the origin in the Access-control-request-headers along with the content-type and when i run the curl commands i get the following: curl -v -X OPTIONS
{"message":"Internal Server Error"} curl -v -X POST
{"message":"Message sent successfully!"}

What's the output with curl -v but without the Origin change?

I am getting message":"Internal Server Error when trying to test it with curl -v command for options in the terminal. In the browser its giving me the same error: Access to fetch at 'https://cl4dhs3yg7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/contact' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Are you using a Lambda Integration or a HTTP Integration in AWS?  If you're using a Lambda integration what version of payload format are you using?

@JaromandaX care to comment why the POST was successful when Origin was added to allowed headers?  Still an open question as to why the preflight is failing however.

@Tibrogargan - no idea - all I know is in all of my apps, all my CORS requests include an origin request header, and none of the responses include origin in the allowed headers, yet all CORS requests work.

@JaromandaX I was under the impression that any header that wasn't on the CORS safe list was required in the allowed headers for a preflight response (i.e. * works).  Could easily be mistaken, and a cursory search doesn't turn up anything that clarifies.  It'll be buried in the specs I'm sure.

The way I look at it, the "safe headers" list is a list of headers that can be set/changed in a request that won't trigger a preflight. Origin, among many others (Host, Referer, User-Agent etc etc), is a header that is sent in every request, is not able to be changed by code, so is always allowed and won't trigger preflight

@Tibrogargan I am using lambda integration and the payload version is 2.0

The issue might be due to an incomplete response for lambda integration version 2.  AWS docs say AWS will infer certain fields, but only if statusCode is not returned.  Since you're including statusCode try also adding content-type and isBase64Encoded headers.

@Tibrogargan i have added the 'Content-Type': 'application/json' and  isBase64Encoded: false in the code but still i am getting the same error. Internal server error when using the curl command in terminal for options and unable to fetch in the browser
